# php json_encode returns blank for array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to return the result of a mysql query as json, but the json_encode function always returns a blank although the array contains elements.

Here is the relevant code

Retrieve the query and convert to php array:

```
$sql = "blablabla";
$clients = mysql_query($sql, $con);

$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($clients)) {
    //echo "rij: " . $row['name'];
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

Then I return the result:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

This returns nothing, while I do get results when echoing the following statements:

```
echo count($return);
```

returns 1

```
echo $return[0];
```

returns "Array"

```
echo $return[0]['name'];
```

returns "YOUREKA! demo"

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Edit: I have one record that is and should be returned which contains following data:

id: 2,
name: YOUREKA! demo,
address: Italiëlei 26,
postalcode: 2000,
city: Antwerpen,
country: België,
countrycode: BE,
telephone: +32-476061346,
email: mats@youreka.be,
distance: 30.762980999827132,

Comment: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) returns `false` on error. What does [json_last_error_msg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) say?

Comment: Can you edit post adding your JSON (undecoded) string?

Comment: U r saving data into an array $result[]

Comment: `$result[] = $row['name'];`

Comment: I want to include all the columns of the recordset in the json, not just the "name" column

Comment: Try this: $result["data"][$row["Id"]] = $row;

Comment: @Kenney, the last error msg returns "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"
I tried adding "mysql_set_charset("utf8");" before and after executing the mysqm query, but this doesn't change the outcome

Comment: Ok. You shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` functions anyway as they are deprecated. Use mysqli, or better, PDO ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466225/import-csv-in-mysql-does-not-work/35467015#35467015) for an example). The trick is in the `SET NAMES utf8` - give that query a try.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) states "All string data must be UTF-8 encoded. ". Your attempts to use `mysql_set_charset` is the right kind of thinking.

Use this kind of debuggery:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

printf("Initial character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I write a demo of php/mysql connection, with json data:** Working fine

```
<?php
// we connect to localhost
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db("db_name")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users where id = 1';
//Query database
$result = mysql_query ($query);
$arr = array();
//Iterate result
while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)){
    $arr[] = $record;
    // print_r ($record);
  }
echo "<pre>".print_r($arr,1)."</pre>";
echo json_encode($arr);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

**Note :** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0